# Why does my simple program did not ends after runs?

Tags: python

Here is my little program: from a set of letters it creates all possible strings.

Problem: I want it to stop after I get the list, PyCharm waits me to press stop button.

```
import random

liste = []
char_list = ['a', 'b', "c", "d"]

while True:

    random.shuffle(char_list)
    n = ''.join(char_list)

    if n in liste:
        continue
    elif n not in liste:
        print(''.join(char_list))
        liste.append(n)
    else:
        break
```

Why is this program did not stops after gives the list ?

Comment: What's in `liste` after the first iteration? (Hint: put `print(liste)` right after `while True`)

Comment: What is the case where it hits `else`?

Comment: Go through the code line by line and ask yourself what you want it to do vs. what you're telling it to do.

Comment: It doesn't end because you made it impossible to end. Either the item is in the list or not

Comment: loop is running infinitely in your program because the break in your else block will never run

Comment: How can i stop it, after all possible strings done ?

Comment: Why do you use an infinite loop?

Comment: @nicolallias it is an error, how can i get list without error ?

Answer (score 6):

It never stops because of your conditions.

```
    # If n is in liste...
    if n in liste:
        continue
    # Otherwise, if n not in liste...
    elif n not in liste:
        print(''.join(char_list))
        liste.append(n)
    # Will never happens, because either n is or is not in liste...
    else:
        break
```

Comment: `char_list` will never be empty. Instead, calculate how many possible combinations you can make (hint: 5! = 120) and `elif len(liste) == 120: break `

Comment: The original question was edited, that goal wasn't mentioned at first.

Comment: with this code it is not give me all all possible strings. Just
dcba
adbc
bcda
dabc

Comment: It doesn't. Your original question wasn't mentioning that goal. Look at Sheri's answer, it should cover your new goal.

Comment: Well,
I want to get all possible strings. I get it with my code. But program did not stop after work.
it gives 
cbda
abcd
dbca
adcb
dbac
acdb
acbd
bcad
bcda
bdac
dacb
dabc
abdc
bdca
cabd
cdba
adbc
cdab
dcab
cadb
dcba
bacd
cbad
badc

But after this it is goes infinitely loop

Answer (score 4):

You never reach the else. Either n is in the list, or it's not. S once you have all the permutations of the characters in your list, the first if-condition is always true und you continue running through it until infinity.

If you want all combinations, do this:

```
from itertools import permutations;
liste = [''.join(x) for x in permutations('abcde')]
```

Answer (score 2):

As been pointed out earlier your program never stops because the `else` statement will never happen. Rather you want to stop when you have created all combinations. Using 4 different characters you can create 24 distinct [permutations](https://brilliant.org/wiki/permutations/) (combinations where order matters). So stop when `len(liste) == 24`.

```
import random
import math

liste = []
char_list = ['a', 'b', "c", "d"]
possible_combinations = math.factorial(len(char_list))    

while True:

    random.shuffle(char_list)
    n = ''.join(char_list)

    if n in liste:
        continue
    elif n not in liste:
        print(''.join(char_list))
        liste.append(n)
    elif len(liste) == possible_combinations:
        break
```

And as someone else pointed out, use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) if this is for something else than homework.

Comment: Can't it find 120 number it self and stops software ?

Comment: @onurhanozer see my updated answer. Use `math.factorial(n)` to calculate number of possible permutations for a list of lenght `n`.

Comment: You don't need a loop. The standard library has functions for stuff like this. itertools.permutations is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for itertools.product.
If you want to generate combinations of character from your char_list so you can try this approach:

```
from itertools import product

char_list = ['a', 'b', "c", "d"]
combs = [''.join(comb) for comb in product(char_list, repeat=len(char_list))]
print(combs)
```

Comment: hmm, this is gives an array, can i get it like list ?

Comment: This gives you a list, but it includes combinations like "dddd" which is not what you want I guess.